# Do Faddeev-Popov ghost contribute to vacuum polarisation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, feynman-diagrams, gauge, ghosts

I can imagine how one can draw a Feynman diagram for a boson self-energy with a ghost loop. My question is, shouldnt't the amplitude of that process be 0 as the ghosts are merely a mathematical tool?

Answer (score 4):

As long as the ghosts are not external particles they can give non-zero contributions to amplitudes, including for boson self-energies. Recall that the Feynman diagrams are just a graphical representation of a mathematical perturbation series.